# Открыть билд Console application на мак

Tags: macos, dll, visual-studio-2015, terminal, build

Скачал Visual studio for Mac. забилдил консольную апликаху. Как открыть апликаху

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как открыть Chat.dll. Через терминал не получается 
открывается просто это 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/tutorials/using-on-macos

Comment: там не написано про сборку

Comment: Dll не открываются, это библиотеки.

Comment: тут ничего не открывается

Comment: Создали тестовый проект?

Comment: da_____________

Comment: в папке bin или obj открывать

Comment: Сделайте как в статье написано. Я сама не делала, наверное, в bin